# Error establishing connection to Binance via Tungstenite Websocket API

Tags: rust, websocket

I am trying to establish a connection to the binance websocket server with the code:

```
use tungstenite::{connect, Message};
use url::Url;

fn main() {
    let (mut socket, response) =
        connect(Url::parse("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/BNBBTC@aggTrade").unwrap()).expect("Can't connect");

    println!("Connected to the server");
    println!("Response HTTP code: {}", response.status());
    println!("Response contains the following headers:");
    for (ref header, _value) in response.headers() {
        println!("* {}", header);
    }
}
```

with `Cargo.toml` containing:

```
[dependencies]
tungstenite = "0.17.3"
url = "2.3.1"
```

I am getting the error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Can't connect: Http(Response { status: 400, version: HTTP/1.1, headers: {"server": "awselb/2.0", "date": "Sat, 22 Oct 2022 20:23:40 GMT", "content-type": "text/html", "content-length": "220", "connection": "close"}, body: None })', src/main.rs:6:90
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/core/src/panicking.rs:142:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/core/src/result.rs:1814:5
   3: core::result::Result<T,E>::expect
             at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/core/src/result.rs:1064:23
   4: untitled12::main
             at ./src/main.rs:6:9
   5: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:248:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
```

What is the reason behind this error? What am I missing? It seems like a bad request error, however my request is supposed to be well-formed according to  the [binance websocket API](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#aggregate-trade-streams)

Comment: still panics at line ```connect(Url::parse("ws://stream.binance.com:9443/ws").unwrap()).expect("Can't connect");```

Comment: I tried another request mentioned in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65750685/4645121 , it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

By default, tungstenite [does not have TLS enabled](https://github.com/snapview/tungstenite-rs/#features), so I had to enable in `Cargo.toml`:

```
tungstenite = { version = "0.17.3", features = ["native-tls"] }
```